# Minimizing a function with two layers

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, gradient

I'm working on optimal transport and i have to solve this problem:

[image]

where

[image]

where [image] have been simulated.

I can approximate T the transfer plan and the function u as [image] and try to find the theta and w with neural networks.

Using Arrow_Huwicz algorithm I have the following simple program : we draw some k in [1,N] and we minimize in w and [image] this function iteratively , such that at step n, [image] and [image]
until itermax is attained

```
def Arrow_Hurwicz_algorithm(dim,NMC,S12,itermax):
w = torch.autograd.Variable(torch.rand(dim, 1), requires_grad=True)
theta = torch.autograd.Variable(torch.rand(dim, 1), requires_grad=True)
step_size = 1e-6
for i in range(itermax):
    k = randrange(NMC)
    L = JN(S12,k,theta,w)
    L.backward()
    theta.data -= step_size * theta.grad.data # step
    F = JN(S12,k,theta,w)
    F.backward()
    w.data += step_size * w.grad.data
    w.grad.data.zero_()
    theta.grad.data.zero_()
optw = w.detach().numpy()[0][0]
optth = theta.detach().numpy()[0][0]
return JN2(S12,optth,optw)
```

How can i perfrom the same thing using Adam stochastic gradient in pytorch ?

Comment: Could you please type your equation using [online-latex](https://codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php), the equations in the question are hard to read.

Comment: I need at least 10 reputation XD , i can post it a link on quant exchange i guess

Comment: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/57584/how-to-use-neural-networks-to-solve-this-problem-efficiently

Answer (score 0):

First I'd like to point out that [the use of torch.Variable is deprecated](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#variable-deprecated).

Pytorch backprop is only able to **minimize** a function. But fortunately, the gradient is a linear operation, so we can minimize `-J` instead. That would yield something like :

```
def Arrow_Hurwicz_algorithm(dim,NMC,S12,itermax):
    w     = torch.rand(dim, 1, requires_grad=True)
    theta = torch.rand(dim, 1, requires_grad=True)
    step_size = 1e-6
    w_opt     = torch.optim.Adam([w], lr=step_size)
    theta_opt = torch.optim.Adam([theta], lr=step_size)

    for i in range(itermax):
        k = randrange(NMC)
        L = JN(S12,k,theta,w)
        # Minimizing JN w/ respect to theta
        L.backward()
        theta_opt.step()
        # Maximizing JN with respect to w
        F = JN(S12,k,theta,w)
        (-F).backward()
        w_opt.step()

    optw = w.detach().numpy()[0][0]
    optth = theta.detach().numpy()[0][0]
    return JN2(S12,optth,optw)
```